# Angular 5 Upgrade Error: Generic type 'InjectionToken<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: angular, angular5

I am upgrading my project from Angular 4.2 to Angular 5. I've followed the instructions on the Angular Update Guide including the part where it says "Replace OpaqueTokens with InjectionTokens". So I replaced OpaqueToken in all of my node_modules with InjectionToken.

Webpack is still failing to compile and I am getting the error:

**"TS2314: Generic type 'InjectionToken' requires 1 type argument(s)."**

EDIT: The OpaqueTokens are in the node_modules not my code (there were 100+ OpaqueTokens). None of the OpaqueTokens had types and its not entirely clear what type the InjectionTokens would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the standalone InjectionTokens needed to be `InjectionToken<object>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you show an example of how you are using the InjectionToken?

From a quick look-up, it seems that InjectionToken requires a `desc` argument to be passed in. I'd check to see if you are doing that correctly.

I'd also refer to the [Angular tutorial on dependency injection and how to use tokens to make unique dependencies](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action)

Comment: [Here is the documentation on InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken)

Comment: I did not find the answer in the documentation or tutorials